# Trying to upload files from google drive in my website

Tags: php, json, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload files from google drive in my website. I am using the code from google api php https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list. The output i get is in JSON array format. Can you please provide me with the php code as in how to parse the JSON to get the title, mimetype of the file from the JSON output.

Answer (score 0):

To get PHP to parse your JSON output, first use json_decode() to create a proper PHP object:

`$data = json_decode($output);`

or, if your output is in a file,

`$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("output.json"));`

The JSON object has an "items" array, with each member of the array representing a file.  Each of these has a "title" property, so to echo the title of the first file, just write

`echo($data->items[0]->title);`

Obviously, you can loop through the $data->items array to list all of them, or whatever you wish.  Similarly, each item has a "mimeType" property that is accessed in the same way.